# How does one create a talk command in Discord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js

Alright, question time! I'm working on this bot, and I'm trying to make it talk on command. Example: !talk (message), and I would want it to repeat that without !talk. Here is my code so far:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).split(" ");
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'talk':

    }
})
```

One more thing, can you make it delete the host message too? Thanks!

Comment: Well, the thing is I think the bot is completely finished.

Comment: That seemed more like an insult than anything. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, just remove the command from `args` and send the `args`, something like this:

```js
if(!args[1]) return message.channel.send("Send some message") //Check if the user sent some message ("talk message"), if didn't return a message
message.delete() //Delete the command
message.channel.send(args.slice(1).join(" ")) //Remove the command from args array and send the message
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can just do:

```
message.delete()
```

to delete the command and then to make it repeat 'talk', just do:

```
message.channel.send('talk')
```

Comment: That's not the question, I mean like you say !talk Hi for example, and it would repeat "Hi".

Comment: Well you can just send args[1]

Comment: I tried it, but it said "true". I added:
if(!args[1]) message.channel.send(!args[1])